# For accessing some pages a logged in user needs to answer some questions, once answered correctly, user will not have to answer again

Tags: rest, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

For authenticating a user I am using keyCloak to get an access token. Some of the pages of application (ex: profile) needs to provide more information(User needs to answer some questions set by him earlier). Once the user's answers are validated, user should not be required to answer the questions again.

I am a beginner in JWT and keycloak. What is the best way to implement the above scenario?

As per my understanding, there should be 2 different tokens now, one will established that the user is authenticated for login and another will establish that user is authenticated for accessing profile page. If it's correct, how can I implement this in keycloak?

If not keycloak, what is the best way to implement this? I was reading the information available about keycloak but unable to get in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to fill more info about him and to store this info at keycloak, you should consider implementing custom [Required Action Spi](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_development/index.html#required-action-walkthrough). Also check out implementation of "Update Profile" required action.